# How to deploy/make .exe/publish a Visual Studio DirectX game?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directx, directx-9

I created this game 2 years ago, but was never able to figure out how to publish it so I can put it on my portfolio. The build menu doesn't have an option to publish.

Any ideas?

Thanks [image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [setup package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353) for it and upload it somewhere. People will have to download the installer, so you have to make sure that every needed file is contained in the package.

You can also think about rebuilding it as Windows Store app. If you don't have to change much you could submit it to the Windows Store for certification. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166870.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to follow your first link's instructions, but there is no such option as "Setup and Deployment Projects" in the New Project Window...

Comment: Apparently, it's no longer supported in VS2012. There are some instructions on how to enable InstallShield Limited Edition under "other project types". You may want to have a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500(v=vs.100).aspx) for a comparison of different deployment solutions.